# Performance issues after installing an SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, graphics-card, performance, framerate

I have a laptop ASUS N550JK with the following specs:

- Intel core i7-4710HQ @ 2.50 GHz,
- 8 GB of RAM,
- NVidia GeForce GTX 850M,
- HDD storage of 677 GB (strange number, I know).

Until last week I was able to play some games quite well, in particular Rainbow 6 Siege run at 40-50 fps, then I decided to upgrade my system installing an SSD (Crucial MX500). I reinstalled Windows and all the heavy programs (games too) on the SSD in order to shorten the loading times, but the in-game performances dropped drastically: now Rainbow 6 runs below 30 fps, unplayable. I don't notice any issues elsewhere: Windows boots and runs fine, all the loading times improved as expected.

What I tried:

- all the energy-saving settings are set to performance, both on Windows and NVidia Experience,
- checked that the games actually run on the NVidia GPU and not on the iGPU,
- reinstalled and updated all the drivers,
- reinstalled Rainbow 6 on the HDD,
- checked the SSD 4K partition alignment (as suggested in a comment).

None of these things restored my previous performances.

Do you know what could be the problem and how to solve it? I really don't get how an SSD could affect performance, any clues?

**EDIT:** I should stress that I don't really know if the problem is due to the SSD itself or maybe something went wrong during the clone of Windows. I only know that the problem appeared *after* the installation of the SSD, but I don't know if it's due to it ^^

**EDIT 2:** I checked again and I found out that the SSD is actually connected to a SATA 2, so at a speed of 3 Gb/s instead of 6, could this be the problem?

**EDIT 3:** After my last update I also tried connecting the SSD to the SATA3 port, but nothing changed. Then I installed an old graphic driver, but it didn't work as well... To make it short, the problem disappeared after I installed Realtek HD Audio and updated the audio drivers from there. I don't know why, but this solved my problem.

PS: sorry for my English, I'm Italian ^^"

Comment: Have you check your SSD? Please ensure it is working properly.  Please ensure that your SSD has got SSD partition 4K alignment. For your reference: https://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/ssd-alignment-windows-10-3889.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I checked the alignment as your link explains and it seems to be fine.
Maybe I should clarify that I don't really know if the problem is due to the SSD itself or maybe something went wrong during the clone of Windows. I only know that the problem appeared AFTER the installation of the SSD ^^

Comment: Are there any other issues with the performance besides a low frame rate in the game?

Comment: With regards to SATA I, if that was the cause, you would have always had the performance issues

Comment: @montonero I can't see any other issues. Every game runs far worse of course, but I don't even know what to check if I don't know the problem :P
Can you suggest any test I could try?

Comment: @Ramhound No, because my HDD has always been connected to the SATA 3. I will try in the following days to swap them and see if something changes, but I don't think it will make any difference. I will let you know in any case by updating my post

Comment: If you do not see any noticeable performance issues (except in games) then most probably there's none. I'd concentrate on a video subsystem: check overheating, drivers etc.

Comment: I will update my post because finally I solved the problem. I still don't know why it happened, but still...